# Android Studio won't find any local modules I import

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

Android studio will successfully import local modules (Android project modules) but won't actually find them. If I change the same module to just a java-library, then it will work fine and find those dependencies. I'm really not sure why. The app successfully compiles with attempting to include the given module, however when I try to reference a class from the imported module, it doesn't find it. ./gradlew app:dependencies thinks it's importing it but it can't find it still. AFAIK this is the exact same setup I'ved used in various other projects but I'm not seeing any differences.

**build.gradle for tasks**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.danielhartman.tasks"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation Libs.support_annotations
    implementation Libs.support_appcompat_v7
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation Libs.room_imp
    kapt Libs.room_annotation_processor
    implementation project(path: ':common', configuration:'default')
    implementation Libs.recyclerview
    implementation Libs.livedata
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

**build.gradle for app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.danielhartman.lyfe"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation"com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation project(path: ':tasks', configuration:'default')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(path: ':tasks', configuration: 'default')
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: There are two other modules 'tasks' & 'common'. For which You are facing errors in the main App module? Ideally, You should be able to access files from 'tasks'

Comment: Yup. As I was typing a response to you I realized that I had it as an application instead of a library. Changing it to a library fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I realized I was using 
`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`instead of`apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`.